# Inner/Outer join issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables orders and customers with data as:

```
mysql> select * from orders;
+---------+----------------+----------+-------+
| orderid | product        | customer | price |
+---------+----------------+----------+-------+
|     292 | sofa           |      101 |  6000 |
|     293 | table          |      105 |  3000 |
|     294 | table          |      104 |  1450 |
|     295 | table          |      101 |  1200 |
|     296 | chair          |      103 |   800 |
|     297 | dressing table |      104 |  9000 |
|     298 | corner         |      102 |  1000 |
|     299 | corner         |      102 |   900 |
|     300 | bed            |     NULL |  NULL |
|     301 | door           |     NULL |  NULL |
+---------+----------------+----------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from customers;
+--------+----------+-----------+
| custid | name     | location  |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|    101 | jaspreet | New delhi |
|    102 | harpreet | Jalandhr  |
|    103 | surjit   | Amritsar  |
|    104 | harneet  | ludhiana  |
|    105 | hashar   | New Delhi |
|    106 | harneet  | NULL      |
+--------+----------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When i run inner join, it return the following data:

```
mysql> select orders.orderid,customers.name from orders inner join customers where orders.customer=customers.custid;
+---------+----------+
| orderid | name     |
+---------+----------+
|     292 | jaspreet |
|     295 | jaspreet |
|     298 | harpreet |
|     299 | harpreet |
|     296 | surjit   |
|     294 | harneet  |
|     297 | harneet  |
|     293 | hashar   |
+---------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But the outer joins are not working on this.

```
mysql> select orders.orderid,customers.name from orders left join customers where orders.customer=customers.custid;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use n ear 'where orders.customer=customers.custid' at line 1

Can someone help me with this concept?

Thanks in advance

Comment: explicitly using `join` key word needs `on` key word to replace `where`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JOIN` condition is specified with `ON`, not `WHERE`:

```
SELECT orders.orderid, 
       customers.name 
FROM   orders 
       LEFT JOIN customers 
              ON orders.customer = customers.custid;
```

You should use this with both inner and outer joins. `WHERE` should be used for conditions on individual tables, not joining conditions.

You were able to get away without this for the inner join because a join without an ON clause performs a full cross product, and then the `WHERE` clause filters based on testing across this. I'm not sure why, but you can't do this with outer join.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The only issue was trying where in the inner join. Your clarification solves that doubt as well that how "where" is implemented in inner. I actually executed the inner join select orders.orderid,customers.name from orders inner join customers ; without any where clause and it did give me a full cross product. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `ON` not `WHERE`:

```
SELECT orders.orderid, 
       customers.name 
FROM   orders 
       LEFT JOIN customers 
              ON orders.customer = customers.custid;
```